# Simple mono-droid login

Tags: c#, android, mono, asp.net-mvc-4, xamarin.android

I have a website which has member login written in MVC4 .NET, it uses the standard WebSecurity login. Each member has products . Basically I want to create an app that allows a user to login and then download their products in a new view.

I cannot find any examples with this functionality on mono-droid samples, can anyone provide assistance or direction? I cannot even seem to direct to a new Layout, Does each layout need an activity? If so how do you define this to a Layout:

I have this below:

```
[Activity(Label = "Products" , MainLauncher = true , Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
        int count = 1;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Login);

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

            button.Click += this.Login;


        }

        private void Login(object sender , EventArgs e)
        {

            // LOGIN TO WEB SITE, IF SUCCESSFULL
            // go to main
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            //else toast incorrect password

        }
```

Any help would be appreciated, I assume LINQ to SQL cannot be used to connect to the Web Server database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the login procedure there are several ways of doing it but the easiest would be a Web Service, especially if you are logging in from an external connection (eg. 3G connection). A simple example would be a Web Service that takes a username and password as parameters and returns true or false if the user has authenticated. A more complex example would be a Web Service that returns a token or Guid that can expire (similar to a web session) and is used to authenticate each additional request to the database.

[Here](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/guides/Application_Fundamentals/Introduction_to_Web_Services) is a tutorial on how to consume a web service using Mono for Android

Once you have authenticated the user you would begin a new `Activity`. The Android OS keeps track of the `Activity` tree; as you start and finish Activities the tree grows and shrinks. The Activity tree keeps a history on all Activities that have been started but not finished. This enables the user to navigate back through the tree using the back button. [Here](http://docs.xamarin.com/Android/Guides/Application_Fundamentals/Activity_Lifecycle) is some more information on the Activity Lifecycle.